# Recursively Removing Vowels from a Linked List - Logic Error

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm using recursion to remove the vowels from a linked list of nodes (data: char) with StringBuilder functionality called MySB2 - just looking for a way to challenge myself a bit and better understand recursion with linked lists.
But I've run into a logic error. I've added some print statements that show that my methods are removing the vowels and keeping the consonants - which is great. But when I go to print the mutated linked list (via my fully functioning toString() method), it does this:
***Before:*** Happiness is All About Love
**After:** Hpnsslbutv

Here is my code:

```
//The calls in my main are below
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
     System.out.println("\nTesting remove vowels method");
     b1 = new MySB2("Happiness is All About Love");
     System.out.println("Before: " + b1);
     b1.removeVowels();
     System.out.println("After: " + b1);
}

//These methods below are within the linked list class, MySB2
public class MySB2
{
     public MySB2 removeVowels()
     {
         noVowels(firstNode, 0);
         //firstNode is the reference to the 1st node in the linked list
         return this;
     }

     private MySB2 noVowels(CNode curr, int i)
     {

         if(curr != null)
         {
             if(isAVowel(curr) != true)
             {
                 System.out.println("noVowels() keeping: " + curr.data);
                 noVowels(curr.next, i++);
                 return this;
             }
             else if(isAVowel(curr) == true)
             {
                 i++;
                 CNode nodeBefore = getNodeAt(i-1);
                 CNode nodeAfter = curr.next;
                 System.out.println("noVowels() removing: " + curr.data);
                 nodeBefore.next = nodeAfter;
                 length--;
             }
             noVowels(curr.next, i++);
         }
         return this;
     }
     private boolean isAVowel(CNode curr)
     {
         char c = Character.toLowerCase(curr.data);
         if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
         {
             //System.out.println("isAVowel() is detecting: " + c);
             //returning true for the proper letters
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me understand where I when wrong logically. And maybe help me figure out how to not do this again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
noVowels(curr.next, i++);
```

you are passing the original value of `i` to the recursive method. You probably want to pass the incremented value, which would require

```
noVowels(curr.next, ++i);
```

or

```
noVowels(curr.next, i+1);
```

choosing which one of those two options to use depends on whether or not you want the value of `i` to still be incremented once the method returns. However, it looks like it doesn't matter which of the two options you choose in your code, since your method always returns immeidately after making a recursive call, so it doesn't matter what's the value of `i` after it returns.

EDIT :

Actually there are several issues with your logic. I can't test it, but this should work :

```
     if(curr != null)
     {
         if(!isAVowel(curr))
         {
             System.out.println("noVowels() keeping: " + curr.data);
         }
         else
         {
             //i++; don't increment i, since you want to remove the current node
             CNode nodeBefore = getNodeAt(i-1);
             CNode nodeAfter = curr.next;
             System.out.println("noVowels() removing: " + curr.data);
             nodeBefore.next = nodeAfter;
             length--;
         }
         return noVowels(curr.next, i+1); // you only need one recursive call
     }
     return this;
```

EDIT2 :

This code still doesn't handle the case where the first node is a vowel.

Comment: I may still be confused, I just tried changing the recursive calls to `noVowels(curr.next, ++i);` or `noVowels(curr.next, i+1);` but ran into some StackOverFlowErrors

Comment: Afraid I've run into an IndexOutOfBoundsException at the "L" in the word "Love" when I tested it, even when using 1 (2nd index) as the i variable rather than 0 (1st index). Would you be able to explain some of my logic errors to me?

Comment: @Her It's impossible to answer without seeing the full implementation of your linked list.